# How do I parse text file in python to create a sorted list with duplicates removed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is  four lines of a sample text file...

> The Star Schema is the simplest style of data mart schema
>
> The star schema consists of one or more fact tables referencing any
>   number of dimension tables
>
> Pay attention to bogus schema
>
> Cheers

A python code should create a sorted list in an alphabetic order as shown below with duplicate words removed and capital words come sorted first.

Final output like this...

```
[ “Cheers”, “Pay”, “Schema”, “Star”, “The”, “any”, “bogus”,………..]
```

Comment: is `schema != Schema`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps you should follow:

1. read the file into a list of lines
2. parse the lines into words, and
   add them to your list
3. remove duplicates
4. sort

This code should do it:

```
import re # use this library for splitting off words

all_words = [] # initialize list to store the words

with open('my_file.txt') as f: # best way to open a file
   for line in f:
       line = line.strip() # remove trailing newline
       words = re.split(r'\W+', line) # split the line into words even when you have punctuation
       all_words += words

# looping is done now, and all lines have been read

all_words = set(all_words) # remove duplicates
all_words = sorted(all_words) # sort (capitalized words will come first)
```

Comment: Excellent response. It worked like a magic. I wish I can think like you do. Please watch out for more questions, I amy count on you for a solution like this. However, How can I solve without using "import re" library? How do I make the best use of append() to append all words to the list?

Comment: Instead of "all_words+=words" in your above code why this does not work --->  all_words= all_words.append(words)? I reiterate my question, how do I use append() method to append all the words in the list as I read and parse each line. Just learning from the master for education purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @Samuel `all_words.append(words)` would add the *list* `words` as a member of `all_words`. What you want is to add *each element* of `words` into `all_words`. You can do this with `all_words.extend(words)` There's a good example right here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend)

Comment: Harold, pardon me for writing back to you. It did work but this is what I was looking for. My sincere apology, I should have been explicit from the beginning. This is what I was looking for.....Of course, open a text file to read; create an empty list and populate this list as I read line by line entire file. If the first line I read has duplicates in it then remove it and split the line into words and put it in an empty list. Now read second line and if the word exist in the list then remove it since we don't want duplicates and if it is new then append it to the list and finally sort, print.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted(s.split())` to sort a string the way you want to:

```
>>> s = 'The Star Schema is the simplest style of data mart schema'
>>> sorted(s.split())
['Schema', 'Star', 'The', 'data', 'is', 'mart', 'of', 'schema', 'simplest', 'style', 'the']
```

For removing the duplicates you can use `set`, however `set` is unordered, therefore you need to convert it into the list again (which will be done implicitly by `sorted`):

`sorted(set(s.split()))`

should be a final answer.
How to read string from files should be pretty easy.

Comment: `sorted(set(s.split(' ')))` should be enough.

Comment: You don't need to specify the `" "`, you would also want to call lower on the string before splitting if Schema == schema.

Comment: You could also `str.rstrip(string.punctuation)` to remove the punctuaution from the words.

Comment: I just learned that innstead of sort() sorted() works. Thank you for your candid response. I will give it a try.